# application to manage software configuration

Tags: monitoring, resource-management

Is there any comprehensible application what can allow me to track all the servers the organization am working for has(not cluster management though). I mean by that a way to see the specs of the servers, what has been deployed to that server. how much memory is consumed by `tomcat`, `mysql`.`total hard drive` , etc.

Please if you know also opensource ones , that would be great

Comment: You're looking for an inventory management system, and there are many out there. None of them are point-n-click, though; all require at least some per-server config on some servers. Also, product recommendations, including recon, is explicitly off topic in the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource usage monitoring and configuration management are two separate topics. For configuration management, you can use a tool like puppet, chef or cfengine. For monitoring there are tools like nagios (alerting) and graphite (graphing, trending). All of these tools are open source.